# Find new records in database table

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0, data-structures

I have `Statistic` table with these fields `Id` `UserId` `DateStamp` `Data` 
Also there is `User` table in database which has `CreditsLeft`(int) field. I need to create function(let's name it `FindNewRecordsAndUpdate`) which will read `Statistic` table every 10 minutes from my application  and decrease `CreditLeft` field by number of new `Statistic` records found for specified user.
My main concern is when I execute `FindNewRecordsAndUpdate` function next time how to find new records in `Statistic` field and skip already counted ones? I could add Counted(bool) field in `Statistic` and set True for already "used" records but maybe there is better solution withotu adding new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least 3 other options:

1. Use a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). So when rows are inserted into the Statistic table, the balance is User is automatically updated
2. Just do an [aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) on demand over the Statistic table to get the SUM(Data)
3. Use an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to "pre calculate" the SUM in point 2

Personally, I'd go for point 2 (and point 3 depending on query frequency) to avoid denormalised data in the User table.

Comment: Not sure about point 2, because Statistic table may grow up to 10 millions records.

Comment: @Tomas: 10 million records is nothing. Remember you'll filter to a given user anyway most likely. But if it becomes too much, you have point 3 anyway